# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Tags: android

I am new to Android.  I just installed Android Studio and am getting this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt when it builds the **predefined code** in android studio.
```